# How to tell CMake to find the lib in local folder through command line?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link my local version of gflags (which is in ~/mylibs/gflags) while compiling google-test. In gtest's CMakeLists.txt, it's using find_package:

```
if (WITH_GFLAGS)
  find_package (gflags 2.2.0)

  if (gflags_FOUND)
    set (HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS 1)
    determine_gflags_namespace (gflags_NAMESPACE)
  endif (gflags_FOUND)
endif (WITH_GFLAGS)
```

I don't want to modify the CMakeLists.txt file. Is there anyway to tell cmake to find the package in my folder ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [gflags documentation](https://gflags.github.io/gflags/#cmake) describes specifying the location of a non-standard installation when using CMake:

> The `gflags_DIR` variable must be set to the `<prefix>/lib/cmake/gflags` directory containing the gflags-config.cmake file

In your case, this might look like:

```
cmake -Dgflags_DIR=/home/blackball/mylibs/gflags/lib/cmake/gflags [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are integrating `gflags` as subproject in a super cmake, you basically want find_package() to be a no-op if you have it in your "meta-project" source dir. This can be done by overloading the `find_package()` command.

Top CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Use find_package everywhere, no-op if it's a subproject
macro(find_package)
  if(NOT TARGET ${ARGV0} AND NOT TARGET ${ARGV0}::${ARGV0})
    _find_package(${ARGV})
  else()
    if(TARGET ${ARGV0})
        get_target_property(TGT_VER ${ARGV0} VERSION)
        set(TGT ${ARGV0})
    else()
        get_target_property(TGT_VER ${ARGV0}::${ARGV0} VERSION)
        set(TGT ${ARGV0}::${ARGV0})
    endif()
    message(STATUS "Found ${ARGV0}: CMake Target ${TGT} (found version \"${TGT_VER}\")")
    set(${ARGV0}_FOUND TRUE)
  endif()
endmacro()
```

note: for gflags you may need to "force" gflags_NAMESPACE also since gflags it's a source not a binary (cf glog issue ToDo)